# javafx change size of swingNode

Tags: java, javafx, swingutilities

i wrote an simple app in JavaFx and wanna use swingNode in it,So i had a problem with change the size or position of my node

```
public class SwingFx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start (Stage stage) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

        createSwingContent(swingNode);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        stage.setTitle("Swing in JavaFX");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 250, 150));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JButton jButton = new JButton("Click me!");
                jButton.setBounds(0,0,5,5);
                swingNode.setContent(jButton);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

i set the bounds of the JButton but it doesn't work , when i run the app
the button appear in the center and in it's default width and height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a parent container and set its layout to null if you want `setbounds()` work

```
public class SwingFx extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start (Stage stage) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

        createSwingContent(swingNode);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        stage.setTitle("Swing in JavaFX");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 250, 150));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JButton jButton = new JButton("Click me!");
                jButton.setBounds(10,10,50,50);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(null);
                panel.add(jButton);

                swingNode.setContent(panel);

            }
        });
    }
}
```